# Convert a string to a path of keys in a hash

Tags: ruby

I have a string like `string = "this_is_a_test"` and a hash `hash`. How can I convert the string to a path of keys, so that it returns the value located at: `hash['this']['is']['a']['test']`?

I don't want to simply split the string into an array; I want to use the string as keys to access in a hash. The keys already exist in the hash.

Comment: Yes my mistake, I am indeed referring to a hash.

Comment: By any chance, are you trying to implement a trie ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) works nicely here:

```
hash = "this_is_a_test".split('_').reverse.inject("final value") { |h, s|  {s => h}  }
```

This returns:

```
 {"this"=>{"is"=>{"a"=>{"test"=>"final value"}}}}
```

and:

```
 hash['this']['is']['a']['test']
 => "final value"
```

The explanation here is that each iteration of inject returns a hash that contains the current string as a key, and the previous hash as a value, so each new key contains recursively all the hashes up to this point, including the deepest value that is passed as argument of inject.

This is why the array of keys needs to be reversed, because the hash is created from the inside-out.

**edit**: I believe I didn't understand the question correctly.

You actually meant to access an existing recursive hash.

Assuming the hash has been built using my previous method, accessing the innermost value can be achieved with inject too:

```
"this_is_a_test".split('_').inject(hash) { |h,v| h[v] }
=> "final value"
```

Also note that Ruby 2.3 implements the new `Hash#dig` method, which does exactly this, in a secure way:

```
path = "this_is_a_test".split('_')
hash.dig(*path) # => "final value"
```

Answer (score 0):

could be something like this ?

```
    keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
    values = [1, 2, 3]
    zipped = keys.zip(values)
    => [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
    Hash[zipped]
    => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't get the keys from a string.

Answer (score -1):

you are looking for `String.split()` function

```
var array = "this_is_a_test".split('_');
```

Comment: No that wouldn't do it. That would just create an array from the string. But I want to use the string as keys.